# Rails: Send Email X Days Before Date in Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an `ApplicationMailer` set up to go out to remind my app's users 10 days before a date in the database (whenever a `reminder` is created it has `@reminder.date`, 10 days before which an email needs to go out.

I looked at [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery.html#method-i-deliver_later), which seems to indicate that `deliver_later(wait_until: ____)` in my model is the way to go, so I currently have this as a starting point in `reminder.rb`:

```
after_create :send_reminder_emails

private

def send_reminder_emails
  @reminder.each do |r|
     ReminderMailer.reminder_send(@user, @reminder).deliver_later(wait_until: ***SOMETHING***)
  end
end
```

However, I've looked all over SO and google, I tried looking at the documentation for gems like [`whenever`](https://github.com/javan/whenever), but I can't figure out how to get it to send out *before* a date from the database.

Can anyone direct me to the right way to structure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into Sidetiq, and Sidekiq.

[Sidetiq](https://github.com/endofunky/sidetiq/wiki/Basic-Usage)

[Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)